# How to override mysql parameters if some conditions are met?

Tags: mysql

Imagine that I have two couriers and some packages:

```
|name|proficient
|Jon |cats
|Mike|bugs

|item|container
|cats|cage
|bugs|jar
```

The trick is, if courier is proficient with bugs, then he will carry them in a jar. If not, he will carry them in a box.

Should this be made in the client side or I should make another container? or should I make two types of container for the same item and choose right one with the trigger?

Comment: How do you determine, if one is proficient?

Comment: by inserting new courier. to the right of the name there is the proficiency of employee. Jon is proficient with cats, Mike is proficient with bugs. Proficiency of each one are already known and everybody can take any package. the difference is that the proficient one will take the item in a different container, so Mike will carry bugs in a jar but Jon will have to carry bugs in a box.